# Show for every $CFL$ $L$ that's not $REG$ exists $L_1,L_2$ with $L_1$ is $REG$ and $L_1 \subseteq L_2$ and $L_2$ is not $REG$ and $L \subseteq L_2$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, closure-properties

i want to show that for all $CFL$ and not $REG$ languages $L \subseteq \{0,1\}^*$

exists $L_1,L_2\subseteq\{0,1\}^*$ with:

- $L_1$ is $REG$
- $L_2$ is $CFL$ and not $REG$
- $L_1 \subseteq L_2 $
- $L \subseteq L_2 $  and $L \neq L_2$

I struggle at showing it for all $L$.

What I did so far is some kind of a little sketch.

Let $L_1 = L(01)$ and $L_2 = \{0^n1^n | n \geq 0\}$ then $L_1$ is obviously $REG$ and $L_2$ is obviously $CFL$ and not $REG$

Also $L_1 \subseteq L_2$ and $L \subseteq L_2$ and $L_2 \neq L$

But how do I proceed from here? How do I show it for every $L$?

Comment: What is the purpose of $L_1$? You could always pick $L_1 = \emptyset$ (it is always regular and a subset of $L_2$).

Comment: Also what's the purpose of $L_2$? You can always choose $L_2 = \{0,1\}^*$.

Comment: I actually don't know. That was a question from a test and I still try to find a solution for this question.

Comment: @Steven $L_2$ is supposed to be not regular, so you can't choose $L_2 = \{0, 1\}^*$.

Comment: @Nathaniel, oh I see. That restriction is only mentioned in the title, so I missed it.

Comment: Sorry I edited my question and made it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not going to work.  If $L=\{00\}$ (say) then you will not have $L \subseteq L_2$.

Hint for a better approach: Could $L$ be $\{0,1\}^*$?  Why or why not?

Comment: How do we define $L_2$ then? Since $L \subseteq L_2$ and $L_2 \neq L$

Comment: If we would set $L_2 = \{0,1\}^*$ and $L_1 = \emptyset$ then it would be valid for every $L \subseteq L_2$ right?

Would this be a possible solution or still to imprecise?

Comment: Ah, I forgot that $L_2$ and $L$ are not regular. I think that's the main problem I have. How do I proceed without using a specific example for a CFL language like $\{0^n1^n\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $L$ is not regular it is different than $\Sigma^*$. What would happen if you choose a word $u\notin L$ and consider $L\cup \{u\}$?

Comment: I don't really know where to go with this. Can you drop a another hint? I'm still confused because L needs to be a subset of L2 while simultaneously L != L2. So L2 has to be superset of L.

Comment: $L\cup \{u\}$ is a superset of $L$ that is different of $L$.

Comment: Ah right. So $L \cup \{u\}$ can be used as $L_2$. That way we satisfy $L \subseteq L_2$ and $L \neq L_2$. And $L_1 \subseteq L_2$ is obvious because $L_1$ could be something simple like some arbitrary $w \in L_2$.


Am I missing something?

Comment: I already hinted that $L_1 = \emptyset$ is enough. Also, you would need to prove that $L_2$ is CFL and not regular.

Comment: That's where I struggle as I said in another answers comments.

How do I proceed without using a specific example for a CFL language like $\{0^1^\}$? For a regular $L$ it would be easy because we could use Sigma*, but I have no clue what would be the way for a CFL language...

Comment: I still haven't found a way to show that $L_2$ is CFL and not regular. What would be a good approach?

Comment: Hint: regular languages are closed under set difference and $L$ is a not regular CFL.

Comment: Somehow the hint didn't help me, but can we suppose L is CFL and not regular without proof? If so, because $L_2 \cup \{u\}$ with $u \notin L$, then $L_2$ would also be CFL and not regular because the union just adds one word and not a whole language?

Comment: "can we suppose $L$ is CFL and not regular without proof?" > are you serious? That's litteraly you hypotheses in the question…